# LibGit2Sharp Unresponsiveness

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I've been looking around and I'm looking for a way to make my git files pull, but not loose responsiveness of my launcher. I've done reading on asynchronously and I'm not sure if it's even possible.
Right now I have

```
private void Install() {
       Repository.Clone("Myrepourl", "Localinstall");
}
```

It's a rather large bit of information to pull, so I'd like to give them updates as it moves from Rep as it pulls from 4 repos I have total. IE

```
private void Install() {
       Repository.Clone("url", "local");
       installstatus.Text = "Pulling next repo";
       Repository.Clone("url", "local");
}
```

Can this be ran asynchronously or is it only going to work synchronously?

Comment: You could run the git code in a separate thread using a `Task` or `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: I'll look at Backgroundworker and see if that's something I can use. Thanks Dan.

Comment: Quick Question on that. Do I need to do anything to close out the background worker?

Comment: Not necessarily. When the `DoWork` method completes then you'll get a `RunWorkerCompleted` event, although it wouldn't hurt to `Dispose()` the worker as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the `Clone` in a `Task` with `TransferProgress` events is the way I go about it.

#### Task-based Console Example:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Repository.Clone("https://github.com/sushihangover/SVGKit.Binding", Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "foobar"),
                new CloneOptions { OnTransferProgress = MainClass.TransferProgress });
        }).Wait();
    }

    public static bool TransferProgress(TransferProgress progress)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Objects: {progress.ReceivedObjects} of {progress.TotalObjects}, Bytes: {progress.ReceivedBytes}");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but I don't understand it quite well enough to use it in my own project. Maybe in the future, as of right now I have a total of about a week in my lifetime playing with C#, so I've got a ways to go. And a sidenote, I just recently fell in love with background workers. App is running 10x as smooth as before.

Comment: This example does not work.  VS 2019 .net 4.72.  I can't get either OnTransferProgress or OnProgress to fire.

Answer (score 0):

What I did

```
private async void Install() {
   Repository.Clone("url", "local");
   installstatus.Text = "Pulling next repo";
   await Task.Run(() => Repository.Clone("url", "local"));
}
```